# ошибка при выполнении docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Ищу помощи с построением образа. При выполнении команды docker build появляется ошибка executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./install.sh]: exit code: 127. Docker Desktop Windows. Так же такая же ошибка происходит и на CentOs и на  Mac OS.
Мой dockerfile:

```
FROM dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest

COPY ./docker/CryptoPro_CSP_5.0_for_Linux_(x64,deb) /csp

WORKDIR /csp
RUN ./install.sh


WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Publish .
ENTRYPOINT /dotnet/dotnet app.dll --environment=Production
```

выполняю команду docker build -t dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest --no-cache .

```
C:\buildimage>  docker build -t dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest --no-cache 
.
[+] Building 8.2s (8/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               
 0.5s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 278B                                                                               
 0.3s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  
 0.3s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    
 0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest                                      
 2.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  
 1.3s
 => => transferring context: 15.68kB                                                                               
 0.4s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM 
 dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest@sha256:79b649da4efd80c09839588bad6f1f603e15965  
  0.9s
 => [2/6] COPY ./docker/CryptoPro_CSP_5.0_for_Linux_(x64,deb) /csp                                                 
 0.2s
 => [3/6] WORKDIR /csp                                                                                             
 0.1s
 => ERROR [4/6] RUN ./install.sh                                                                                   
 4.1s
 ------
 > [4/6] RUN ./install.sh:
 #8 4.071 /bin/sh: 1: ./install.sh: not found
 ------
 executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./install.sh]: exit code: 127
```

Так же пробовал различные вариации команды RUN в dockerfile:
RUN chmod +x install.sh
RUN ./install.sh
или
RUN chmod +x install.sh && ./install.sh

Comment: Попробуйте добавить файл install.sh

Comment: @user7860670 вы имеете ввиду с помощью ADD в dockerfile? Я пробовал выводить RUN ls в созданной папке csp. Файл там этот присутствует

Comment: Если файл `instal.sh` в `./docker/CryptoPro_CSP_5.0_for_Linux_(x64,deb)` не исполняемый, то `bash -c ..` выдаст такую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

После изменения dockerfile  все заработало. Теперь интересует вопрос, почему так происходит

```
FROM dockerhub.company.ru/serv/app_base:latest

COPY ./docker/CryptoPro_CSP_5.0_for_Linux_(x64,deb) /csp

WORKDIR /csp
ADD install.sh /csp
RUN ./install.sh


WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Publish .
ENTRYPOINT /dotnet/dotnet app.dll --environment=Production
```

Comment: «почему так происходит?» — а как же может быть иначе? в каталоге `/csp` внутри файловой системы контейнера не было файла `install.sh`. пока вы его туда не скопировали. не понятно, что именно вам тут не понятно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Если внимательно почитать топик. То физически файл этот есть. Я специально для отладки делал RUN ls. Файл есть. При этом этот же dockerfile собирался в образ на другой машине без ошибок.